# Checking for empty variable in PHPTAL condition

Tags: php, conditional-statements, template-tal, phptal

In PHPTAL tal:condition can check is variable empty?
Something like that:

```
< tag tal:condition="var" >Some text< /tag >
```

but the value of variable is like that:

```
<?php
$variable = '';
$Tpl->var = $variable;
?>
```

And it's a problem 'cause PHPTAL that value '' interpreting like not empty value and condition return true.

Next problem is using it when variable is a matrix. Then needed is tal:repeat and I don't know how check each elements of matrix in tal:condition

How fix it in PHPTAL side?

Answer (score 3):

```
<tag tal:condition="php:!empty(var)">Some text</tag>
```

Comment: You should really minimize the use of `php:` in templates as this defeats the purpose of separating view from logic and makes your templates less portable.

Answer (score 2):

`tal:condition` evaluates `''` and arrays with `count($array)==0` as false.

If by martix you mean n-dimensional array, then you'll have to wrtite function that checks it the way you want and use it like in nuqqsa's answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `true`tales to check if a variable is not empty. more information [here](http://phptal.org/manual/en/#tales-true)

it works as PHP's `!empty()` construct.

```
< tag tal:condition="true:var" >Some text< /tag >
```

Hope this help future visitors of this question.